# Graphics on top of a Panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, paintcomponent

I am having trouble with the Graphics that I am drawing on a Panel which has a JLabel on top of it. I am using a custom paintComponent(Graphics g) method to draw a String on the Panel. I want the string to show on top of the JLabel instead of under the JLabel, which is what is currently happening. Here is the paintComponent method if you want to see it:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(a.shouldAnnotate()){
        FontMetrics size= g.getFontMetrics(); 
        if(getWidth()>=(a.dispX()+size.stringWidth(a.annotationText()))){
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(a.dispX()-3,a.dispY()-12,size.stringWidth(a.annotationText())+5,15);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(a.dispX()-3,a.dispY()-12,size.stringWidth(a.annotationText())+5,15);
            g.drawString(a.annotationText(), a.dispX(), a.dispY());
        }else{
            String sub="";
            int letters=0;
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(a.dispX()-3,a.dispY()-12,getWidth(),15);
            g.setColor(Color.black);

            for(int i=0;i<a.annotationText().length();i++){
                if(a.dispX()+letters+16<=getWidth()){
                    sub+=a.annotationText().substring(i,i+1);
                    letters=size.stringWidth(sub);
                }else{
                    sub=sub+"...";
                    i=a.annotationText().length();
                }
            }
            g.drawRect(a.dispX()-3,a.dispY()-12,size.stringWidth(sub)+3,15);
            g.drawString(sub,a.dispX(),a.dispY());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like graphics much but I need to learn the fix of this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this I think that you must either override paint or paintChildren, and draw your text there:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawOverLabel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = 100;
   private static final Font TEXT_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 32);
   private static final int LABEL_COUNT = 40;

   public DrawOverLabel() {
      for (int i = 0; i < LABEL_COUNT; i++) {
         JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
         label.setForeground(Color.green);
         label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 20));
         add(label);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g);

      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.setFont(TEXT_FONT);
      g.drawString("in paint", 20, 30);

//      super.paint(g);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.setFont(TEXT_FONT);
      g.drawString("in paintComponent", 20, 60);

//      super.paintComponent(g);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
      super.paintChildren(g);

      g.setColor(Color.gray);
      g.setFont(TEXT_FONT);
      g.drawString("in paintChildren", 20, 100);

//       super.paintChildren(g);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawOverLabel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawOverLabel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

But a better solution is to use a JLayeredPane or the glasspane for this effect.

Comment: hmmm `paint` / `paintComponent` / `paintChildren` +1

Comment: @mKorbel You usually don't like overriding the `paint` method ;)

Comment: @GETah: he doesn't, nor do I, but sometimes it needs to be done such as when making a JPanel that fades in and fades out. But again, for this problem, I wouldn't do this but instead would layer my components using a JLayeredPane.

Comment: @HoverCraftOfEels thank you, your advise was very good and I love the way you made that application to show me how this works. Appreciate it very much. In this situation though I could't use a JLayeredPane or I would of. Thanks!

Comment: @CaptainGh0st: You're welcome, but why do you feel that you can't use a JLayeredPane? I know of no reason why it would interfere with your program.

Comment: @HoverCraftOfEels I had to make images on the JLabel  which would be put on a Panel so I did not want to make the JLabel a Panel because it might further complicate things down the road. So im guessing (correct me if im wrong) that you cant use JLayeredPane as a substitute for my use of a JLabel

Comment: @CaptainGh0st: I'm confused. The JLayeredPane can hold your JLabels, can hold your background JPanel and can hold your foreground JPanel -- it can hold any sort of JComponent you'd like to put in it. This will easily allow you to draw behind or on top of the JLabels. What you said above, abut JLayeredPane as a substitute for JLabel doesn't make sense to me as it would be used to *hold* the components, not as a substitute for them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This makes more sense now. You have actually taught me alot today. The JLayeredPane would allow to hold components, my understanding was that it was an actual replacement and that you can't put things inside. Thanks! One more question: Say if I want to move those JLabels around when the mouse is dragged. I can't put a mousemotionlistener on the JLabel I would have to put it the JPanel, but then I don't know how to find which JLabel the listener should move. If you are tired of my questions/stupidness I completely understand and I will just make a new question. THANKS!!!

Comment: @CaptainGh0st: you can in fact add a MouseMotionListener to any component including a JLabel. Either that or add it to the JLayeredPane and use the methods available to see which contained JLabel has been clicked on.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels once again got it to work perfectly THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was unable to change the code to a JLayeredPane because I didn't write it, it was written by my group member and he has "a problem with people changing his "perfect code"". Last question I have about layering is that I need to bring the JLabel on top of other JLabels when being dragged, but I cannot seem to find a solution online. Would you happen to know the answer?

Comment: @CaptainGh0st: all classes that extend from Container (including JComponent, JPanel and all other light-weight Swing components) will have the method `setComponentZOrder(Component comp, int index)` that will likely solve your problem if used correctly. Please check out the [Component API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) for more.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels screen.setComponentZOrder(this, 0) solved the problem right away! thanks!